# Qual a pronúncia correcta da palavra "dezoito"?

Tags: pronúncia

Deve ser pronunciada como "dezóito" ou "dezôito"? Ou são as duas aceitáveis?

Comment: Em Portugal, quando alguém diz "dezóito", costumam perguntar: "Também dizes biscóito?". :)

Comment: @Edu …e o primeiro pode retorquir, «E tu que dizes dezôito, nunca dizes óito?» Porque habitualmente quem diz “dezôito” diz “óito”, e vice-versa. Confrontar uma pessoa por causa da sua pronúncia regional não me parece boa ideia.

Comment: @JúlioReis Eu não estava a dizer qual a versão correcta, apenas comentei algo que acontece em Portugal, mais concretamente aqui no Porto. Pois por aqui diz-se "dezôito", "ôito", "biscôito"... :)

Comment: @Edu Cumprimentos a partir do Porto, também :) onde aliás, muito boa gente (que eu conheço) diz “óito”, p.ex. «ainda há óito dias estibe lá». (Sem ofensa, a pronúncia é muito interessante, seja com Ó aberto ou fechado.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pronúncia no português europeu padrão é com *o* aberto — "dezóito". *Dezoito* com *o* fechado ("dezôito") é uma variante regional, usada no norte de Portugal.

Já no Brasil, só se usa a forma com *o* fechado.

Esta [resposta de Carlos Rocha no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-pronuncia-de-dezoito-historia-e-variacao/32811) tem mais detalhes. Na mesma linha da citação de Leite de Vasconcelos aí dada, diz [Ismael Coutinho](https://books.google.nl/books?id=e8pQAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22dezoito%22+%22Leite+de+Vasconcelos%22&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&redir_esc=y) nos seus [*Pontos de Gramática Histórica*](http://www.worldcat.org/title/pontos-de-gramatica-historica/oclc/270062&referer=brief_results):

> O ó de dezóito resultou da contração de o+o da forma arcaica *dezooito* (< dezaoito < **dece ac octo* por *duodeviginti*)

Comment: Nas minhas andanças por terras de além-mar nunca percebi essa diferença.  Em duas semanas estarei por aí novamente e vou prestar atenção a esse detalhe.

Answer (score 0):

Em **Portugal**, pronunciam "**dezóito**" ou "**dezôito**".

No **Brasil**, pronunciam "**dezôito**"

- Você pode verificar a **pronúncia de palavras na voz de nativos** da língua portuguesa aqui: https://forvo.com/pronounce/

Comment: Estás parcialmente correto, pois, há portugueses que falam *dezôito*, com diz a [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/dezoito) e o [Priberam](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/1030).

Comment: Bem observado @Schilive. Obrigado!

Comment: Dei *upvote* no teu comentário para falar que eu li.